How to fix typescript error @types/express-serve-static-core/index has no exported member
I'm facing these errors after changing node from 14.18.0 to 20.16.0:
../node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'CookieOptions'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'Errback'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'Application'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'Express'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'Handler'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'IRouter'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'IRouterHandler'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'IRouterMatcher'
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index"' has no exported member 'MediaType'

../node_modules/@types/passport/index.d.ts
Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' does not satisfy the constraint 'IncomingMessage'. 
Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'IncomingMessage': aborted, httpVersion, httpVersionMajor, httpVersionMinor, and 45 more 

These node packages I'm using

dependencies
@nestjs/common ^7.3.2
@nestjs/config ^7.3.2
@nestjs/core ^7.3.2
@nestjs/microservices ^7.3.2
@nestjs/platform-express ^7.3.2
devDependencies
@types/express 4.17.9
typescript ^3.7.4

Other details:

node 20.16.0
npm 6.14.15

How can I solve these errors with @types/* packages?

I solved it by updating the typescript version:
npm i -D typescript@5.1.6 --save-exact

Or
npm i -D typescript@latest

Credits:
@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts causing build errors
